# Ringing Bell in Macro with Search

Tags: search, isearch, keyboard-macros, bell

It throws the error `After 0 kbd macro iterations: isearch-search: Keyboard macro terminated by a command ringing the bell` and I have no idea why, nor can I find anything about it by searching. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Emacs Wiki, you can't use isearch during a keyboard macro.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros#toc2

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: Not sure.  Actually I found this question after running across this problem.  Maybe the best approach is just using regular search rather than isearch.

Comment: Perhaps this was true in older versions of emacs, but it certainly isn't true now. This is how I do it : when entering a kbd macro, I start Isearch normally, and when I'm happy with the search string I hit RET to exit isearch and perform whatever editing commands I want to do, then hit [F4] (to end the keyboard macro) and again (to repeat it). What is true however is that when there are no more matches, the error message « Terminated by a command ringing the bell » is thrown, but that's harmless : it just means I'm done.

Comment: @YoungFrog Thanks for the info in that last sentence. That should be an answer. I got here because I'm using isearch in a macro but messed my window setup up. So the macro jumped to the wrong window and tried to search there, apparently.

Comment: You _can_ use I-search as long as you don't get a search miss. Without the possibility to use I-search, macros would be close to useless. What we would like to have is to have undo in I-search revert any call to ding. I've been missing that feature as long as I've been using Emacs.

Comment: @Nordlöw it's possible to make it not ding, [just add a defadvice around the func executing the macro](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/78949/2671#ringing-bell-in-macro-with-search).

Comment: ⁻¹ to this answer because as mentioned in the comments *(and as I just tested myself)* isearch works very well during recording/replaying a macro *(barring of course the ding problem)*. I'm not sure what problem the Emacs Wiki refers to as I don't have an access to the mailing list link without a VPN, but I can certainly say it's not good for the completely misleading answer to be at the top and with a checkmark ✓

Comment: @UTF-8 as mentioned in the answer I referred to above, it's possible to make isearch not ding during macro replay.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative mentioned in the [emacs wiki link](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros#toc2) that Kevin Holmes gave works for me in emacs 25.2.1: while recording the macro, type Ctrl+s to start isearch, then type RET to switch to normal search (before typing your search query), then continue from there.

Comment: Is it possible to change the behaviour of I-search to not ring a bell during macro recording? This in order to enable the backspace-correcting of failing I-search queries during macro recording?

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly, that message could be a little more clear. "terminated by a command ringing the bell" means a command went wrong during your macro (threw an error).

Since it happened during isearch, it probably just means the search failed during the keyboard macro. Redo the macro, being careful not to mistype anything during the search.

Comment: I'm 100% sure it's right, but I still have the error.

Comment: @AidanEdwards tell us exactly the keys you're typing

Comment: F3, Ctrl+S, `UnTip()`, Ctrl+R, -there should be a space here but it breaks the mardown-`class=blue10`, Ctrl+S, `onmouseover=`, Ctrl+W, Ctrl+Space, `);"`, Ctrl+W, Ctrl+S, `>`, -typing some stuff-, Ctrl+W, -typing more stuff-, F4

Comment: Just to be clear : if you have the message "Failing I-search" at any point during your macro, this is the problem, even though it doesn't look like a problem during the recording of the macro.

Comment: IMO this is clearly a bug in user interface, which I'm not sure why wasn't reported before, but [here, now there's a report](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=66149)

Answer (score 1):

As [pointed by Juri Linkov](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=66149#16), the behavior is controlled by `isearch-wrap-pause` variable that can be set to `'no-ding` to never "ding".

So the problem can be worked around by having the following code in your init:

```lisp
(defun kmacro-call-macro-advice (orig-func arg &optional no-repeat end-macro macro)
  "Make mistyped search while recording a macro never break the replay"
  (let ((isearch-wrap-pause 'no-ding))
    (funcall orig-func arg no-repeat end-macro macro)))
(advice-add 'kmacro-call-macro :around #'kmacro-call-macro-advice)
```

If you're using Evil-mode plugin, here's a similar fix for its keyboard macros:

```lisp
(defun evil-execute-macro-advice (orig-func count macro)
  "Make mistyped search while recording a macro never break the replay"
  (let ((isearch-wrap-pause 'no-ding))
    (funcall orig-func count macro)))
(advice-add 'evil-execute-macro :around #'evil-execute-macro-advice)
```

---

Note the small change in behavior with these `advice`s: if during the search you reached the bottom of the buffer, search will wrap around and start from the beginning of the buffer. I personally fine with that, just bear in mind.